# MSSQL error: Changed database context to 'dbname'

Tags: php, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to make a connection with the database name 'dbname' using php-mssql. It shows connection is successfully done and connection is open now but when I am trying to execute create table query in that database then I am getting an error as 
MSSQL error: Changed database context to 'dbname'.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$myServer = "123.456.88.99";
$myUser = "user1";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "dbname"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 
echo "connection done ".$selected; 
$query = "CREATE TABLE prasad(customer_name varchar(10), contact_name varchar(10), Address varchar(50), city varchar(50), country varchar(50))";
if(mssql_query( $conn, $query))
{
echo "table creation successfull";
}
else{
    echo "table not created";
    die( 'MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

Note: 
   database server and the hosting server are different servers that is why I have entered ip address in place of '$myServer'.

Comment: this is not the total error,you are getting last error message due to this "'MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message()",please post total error

Comment: `$myDB = "dbname";` that's what you're connecting to. What's the actual error?

Comment: when i run the program the condition fails and the control goes to the else part : table not createdMSSQL error: Changed database context to 'dbname'.

Comment: @VamsiAbbineni I do not copy/paste it on every question and sorry that i have read mysql instead of mssql. Think it is also happend to you some times

Comment: @PriyaSingh : your code doesn't have $conn value. but you are using $conn variable in this line[if(mssql_query( $conn, $query))
]

Comment: @PriyaSingh: please check the code once

Comment: thanks for the hint.I replaced $conn with $dbhandle but it again gives the same error.

Comment: I am getting this error too. 

I use this to connect:-
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$this->db, "UID"=>$this->username, "PWD"=>$this->password, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$dbConn = sqlsrv_connect($this->host, $connectionInfo);

Changed language setting to us_english

The reason this error is occurring is either MSSQL does not handle connections made to it from non Microsoft Visual Studio code very well or PHP is running commands improperly for MSSQL.